# Target all of a certain class, except for a specified instance in SHACL

Tags: shacl

I want to use SHACL to check incoming datasets for construction projects. For this, I defined several constraints at class level. In my use-case i need to be able to make a project specific exception on these constraints for specified instances. Is this possible in SHACL? How can this be modelled?

Eventually, I want to describe these constraints in different Shape Graphs (SG):

- The general SG, which holds the rules without exceptions;
- The project SG, which holds specific project related constraints and exceptions on constraints in the general SG.

I can think of workarounds such as SHACL-SPARQL or checking the against the general SG first and then ignoring the project specific exceptions using a filter, but I'm wondering if there is a more clean solution for this case.

Here is an simplified example to illustrate the problem:

---

The data graph might look like this:

```
@prefix schema: <http://www.example.org/schema#> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/data#> .

schema:Building  a  owl:Class .

:CorrectBuilding a schema:Building ;
  schema:owner "John Doe" ;
  schema:otherProp "Some other prop" .

:IncorrectBuilding a schema:Building ;
  schema:otherProp "Some other prop" .

:BuildingWithException a schema:Building ;
  schema:otherProp "Some other prop" .
```

The general SG might look like this:

```
@prefix schema: <http://www.example.org/schema#> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/data#> .
@prefix gsg: <http://www.example.org/generalsg#>

gsg:PersonShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass schema:Building ;
    sh:property [              
        sh:path schema:owner ;       
        sh:minCount 1 ;
    ] .
```

Using the above and the project specific SG, the validator should return a violation for `:IncorrectBuilding`, but not for `:BuildingWithException`.

**How can I make a project specific exeption for `:BuildingWithException`?**

Thanks for reading and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a case for using [SHACL-AF Custom Targets](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/#targets), if you can use them in your environment:

```
@prefix schema: <http://www.example.org/schema#> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/data#> .
@prefix gsg: <http://www.example.org/generalsg#>
@prefix sh:    <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

gsg: 
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "schema" ;
        sh:namespace "http://www.example.org/schema#" ; 
    ] ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "data" ;
        sh:namespace "http://www.example.org/data#" ; 
    ] .

gsg:PersonShapeWithException
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:target [
        a sh:SPARQLTarget ;
        sh:prefixes gsg: ;
        sh:select """
        SELECT ?node 
        WHERE {
            ?node a schema:Building 
            FILTER (?node != data:IncorrectBuilding)
        }
        """ ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [              
        sh:path schema:owner ;       
        sh:minCount 1 ;
    ] .
```

produces:

```
[ a            sh:ValidationReport ;
  sh:conforms  false ;
  sh:result    [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
                 sh:focusNode                  :BuildingWithException ;
                 sh:resultMessage              "Property needs to have at least 1 values, but found 0" ;
                 sh:resultPath                 schema:owner ;
                 sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
                 sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:MinCountConstraintComponent ;
                 sh:sourceShape                []
               ]
] .
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do this without AF, but I guess this is the only way. Thanks for your solution, great help!